# Will using a bright LED to light my MOC harm my LEGO?

Tags: piece-information, lighting

I'm building a LEGO model and planning on lighting it with a bank of 5 battery operated LEDs. I know sunlight negatively affects several LEGO colors. Will a bright LED harm the elements in my MOC the same way sunlight would?

Comment: I assume these are small, battery operated LEDs? In which case heat shouldn't be too much of an issue - LEGO used to use the older style tungsten bulbs, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultra-violet radiation is emitted primarily by sunlight, mercury lamps, black lights.

LEDs emitting visible light will not produce a significant amount of UV radiation required to discolour LEGO bricks. However, [LEDs can be manufactured to emit UV light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet#Ultraviolet_LEDs),